# Demotion Chess (variant)

Tags: chess-variants

Suppose a player may choose as their move to demote their Queen to a Rook,
or a Rook to a Bishop, or a Bishop to a Knight, or a Knight to a Pawn.
Importantly, if a Knight is on the 8th rank and is demoted to a Pawn, then, without
another move, it can immediately become a Queen (or any other piece).

Two questions:

> (1) Has this chess variant been explored? [*Demotion Chess* is my terminology.]

> (2) Is it perhaps easier to analyze than traditional chess?

Concerning (2), I'm wondering if the special power of placing a Knight on the 8th rank (if White, or 1st rank if Black) might make it easier to analyze---perhaps
determine a winning strategy for White.
It seems prudent to demote Bishops to Knights and aim to place Knights so that demotion to Pawns Queens.

Comment: You can search for "demotion site:chessvariants.com" and find, e.g., this chessvariant: Potential/Demotion by Perter Aronson 2001: https://www.chessvariants.com/usualeq.dir/potentialdemotion.html